# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword. when inserting record to DB using JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ora-00928

I get an error when I try to insert some rows to a db. so here is the code

```
try {
    String insertStmt = "INSERT into " +
                        "MY_TABLE('RECORD_TYPE', 'FILE_TYPE', 'DATE', 'BATCH_NO', 'RECORD_COUNT')" +
                        "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

    PreparedStatement pstmt = super.con.prepareStatement(insertStmt);

    pstmt.setString(1, input[0]);
    pstmt.setString(2, input[1]);
    pstmt.setString(3, input[2]);
    pstmt.setString(4, input[3]);
    pstmt.setString(5, input[4]);

    System.out.println("Insert rows : " + pstmt.executeUpdate());

} catch (SQLException sqle) {
    System.out.println(sqle.getMessage());
    sqle.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    con.close();
}
```

and everything on the db is of varchar type, double checked the columns (they all are the same name), took out the quotes off the column name (same result) no success. to add it up, the error message is not very helpful.

any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Try without the quotes (should be double quotes if any), without the trailing semicolon, and with a space before `values`.

Comment: There's no space between RECORD_COUNT) and VALUES( .. so your insert command looks like 'INSERT into MY_TABLE(......)VALUES(????)`

Comment: I think you'll always need to use the double quotes, since DATE is normally an invalid identifier.  (Which is why you shouldn't use it as a column name.  And plus, why is it stored as a string?)

Comment: You actually don't need a space before `values`, although it normally looks better that way.

Comment: Remove the semicolon before the closing double quotes of the query.

Comment: hey people, thanks for all your suggestions. that space with the values keyword caused the problem. thanks again! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can spot two problems:

1. No need for single quotes around column names. But you may wrap it in double quotes. It is necessary if you are using reserved keywords for column names or table names. Here `DATE`.
2. You need a space before `VALUES`.

So you need to change `insertStmt` to somthing like this:

```
String insertStmt = "INSERT into " +
    "MY_TABLE(RECORD_TYPE, FILE_TYPE, \"DATE\", BATCH_NO, RECORD_COUNT) " +
    "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
```

Comment: Read the OP and title - It is all about **oracle**.

Answer (score 5):

You need to change the `SQL` statement. (Never use reserved words as identifiers)

```
String insertStmt = "INSERT into \"MY_TABLE\" (RECORD_TYPE,FILE_TYPE, 
              \"DATE\",BATCH_NO,RECORD_COUNT) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Use `"` (double quotes) to escape the reserved words/keywords.

Comment: hey man, I was about to answer that here. yep, the date column need to be surrounded by double quotes and then escaped. thanks for the answer :D :D :D

Answer (score 2):

Print insertStmt String in Console and try to fire it in directly backend. It gives you exact error in backend. It seens some spacing or syntax error.

Comment: yep, i tried inserting a record from the db ide and knew that there were some syntax errors. thanks for the answer jwalin. appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

I just came to this page while searching for ORA-00928, and I'd like to note that my problem was an extra comma at the start of the column list:

```
INSERT INTO redacted.redacted
  (
  , redacted_id   -- The comma at the start of this line will trigger ORA-00928.
  , another_redacted_id
  , redacted1
  , redacted2
  , redacted3
  , created_at
  , created_by
  , changed_at
  , changed_by
  )
  VALUES
  (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Answer (score 0):

For others searching for the same error: Other syntactical issues with the query can cause the same exception to be thrown. For example, omitting the word VALUES.

Answer (score 0):

I was running the same issue, and in my case the query was like this:

```
insert into Address (number, street, id) values (?, ?, ?)
```

The problem was caused by the `number` column name since `number` is a reserved keyword in Oracle, and the exception was sort of misleading `ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword`.

After escaping the `number` column, the statement was executed normally:

```
insert into Address ("number", street, id) values (?, ?, ?)
```